# Como dejar desplegado un nav-bar dropdown bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola quería saber como puedo dejar abierto este menú dropdown que esta hecho en bootrstrap 4.

```css
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -43px!important;
  left: 252px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
      padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .hijas-de-hijas{
   position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -42px!important;
  left: 218px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
      padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0; 
}
  .categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active{
    background-color: #f5131f;
    color: #fff!important
  }
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover{
  color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}
.categoria-prod .bg-prod{
 background-color: #f5131f;
}
.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-brand{
 font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler{
 color: #fff;
 border-color:transparent!important;
 outline: none
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler:hover{
  opacity: 0.7
}
.navbar-toggler{
 padding: 3px 10px!important;
  font-size: 26px!important;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none
}
.categoria-prod .btn-category{
 background-color: #ededed;
 border-radius: initial;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #565656;
 padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
 border-color: #bebebe;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container categoria-prod pt-3 pt-lg-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 p-0 pl-lg-0 pr-lg-3">
      <div class=" navbar-dark bg-prod">
        <div class="p-2 px-lg-3 py-lg-3">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Productos</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
               <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
           </button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse px-3 py-2" id="collapsingNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Hierro
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Chapas
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Chapa Acanalada 
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu hijas-de-hijas" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="single.html">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                </div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapa Acanalada dasdda </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapa Acanalada  dasdsad </a>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Perfiles
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Tubos y Caños
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Metal desplegado y Rejillas
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mallas metálicas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Aislaciones y membranas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Clavos y tornillos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Alambres y tejidos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Todo para herrería</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Soldadoras</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Herramientas eléctricas </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Renderizado abierto, se cierra y se abre si clikeas**

En el `div` con id "*collapsingNavbar*", debes agregar la clase "**show**" para que el nav-bar se cargue abierto.
Quedaría así:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show px-3 py-2" id="collapsingNavbar">
```

Si le vuelves a hacer click se cerrara y seguirá su comportamiento normal.

---

**Renderizado abierto y no se cierra**

Ahora bien si quieres que cargue abierto y nunca se cierre ni se abra de manera definitiva, agrega la clase del `div` con id "*collapsingNavbar*" y el `data-target` del botón siguiente:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="">
```

---

***Ejemplo completo:***

Así quedarian agregando **solo** la clase "show"

```css
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -43px!important;
  left: 252px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
      padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .hijas-de-hijas{
   position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -42px!important;
  left: 218px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
      padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0; 
}
  .categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active{
    background-color: #f5131f;
    color: #fff!important
  }
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover{
  color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}
.categoria-prod .bg-prod{
 background-color: #f5131f;
}
.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-brand{
 font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler{
 color: #fff;
 border-color:transparent!important;
 outline: none
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler:hover{
  opacity: 0.7
}
.navbar-toggler{
 padding: 3px 10px!important;
  font-size: 26px!important;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none
}
.categoria-prod .btn-category{
 background-color: #ededed;
 border-radius: initial;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #565656;
 padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
 border-color: #bebebe;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container categoria-prod pt-3 pt-lg-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 p-0 pl-lg-0 pr-lg-3">
      <div class=" navbar-dark bg-prod">
        <div class="p-2 px-lg-3 py-lg-3">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Productos</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
               <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
           </button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show px-3 py-2" id="collapsingNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Hierro
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Chapas
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Chapa Acanalada 
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu hijas-de-hijas" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="single.html">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                </div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapa Acanalada dasdda </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapa Acanalada  dasdsad </a>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Perfiles
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Tubos y Caños
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Metal desplegado y Rejillas
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mallas metálicas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Aislaciones y membranas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Clavos y tornillos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Alambres y tejidos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Todo para herrería</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Soldadoras</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Herramientas eléctricas </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Así quedaría, agregando la clase "show"
 y el `data-target` (se renderiza abierto y no se puede cerrar) :

```css
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -43px!important;
  left: 252px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
      padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .hijas-de-hijas{
   position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -42px!important;
  left: 218px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
      padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0; 
}
  .categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active{
    background-color: #f5131f;
    color: #fff!important
  }
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover{
  color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}
.categoria-prod .bg-prod{
 background-color: #f5131f;
}
.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-brand{
 font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler{
 color: #fff;
 border-color:transparent!important;
 outline: none
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler:hover{
  opacity: 0.7
}
.navbar-toggler{
 padding: 3px 10px!important;
  font-size: 26px!important;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none
}
.categoria-prod .btn-category{
 background-color: #ededed;
 border-radius: initial;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #565656;
 padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
 border-color: #bebebe;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container categoria-prod pt-3 pt-lg-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 p-0 pl-lg-0 pr-lg-3">
      <div class=" navbar-dark bg-prod">
        <div class="p-2 px-lg-3 py-lg-3">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Productos</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="">
               <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
           </button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show px-3 py-2" id="collapsingNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Hierro
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Chapas
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Chapa Acanalada 
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu hijas-de-hijas" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="single.html">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapas prepintadas  </a>
                </div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapa Acanalada dasdda </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapa Acanalada  dasdsad </a>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Perfiles
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Tubos y Caños
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Metal desplegado y Rejillas
                 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mallas metálicas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Aislaciones y membranas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Clavos y tornillos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Alambres y tejidos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Todo para herrería</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Soldadoras</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Herramientas eléctricas </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hola federico, y en caso que se muestre abierto pero quiera cerrarlo? ya ahí seria con javascript no?

Comment: pero en el ejemplo que subiste no lo tiene puesto, osea esta vacio

Comment: entonces vos decis que se va cerrar si yo lo dejo asi: <div class="navbar px-3 py-2" id="collapsingNavbar"> ?? porque probe y nada

Comment: Ahí cambie de approach a uno más correcto. Y te añadí el ejemplo que se cierra para que lo veas funcionando.

Comment: ahh ahora comprendí lo que hiciste, muchas gracias Federico.

Comment: Una ultima cosa quizás esto es as programación si yo quisiera que en resoluciones mas chicas se mantenga cerrado, ya ahí tendría que usar jquery?

Comment: Correcto, deberías usar JQuery o con bootstrap '.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}' dependiendo en que tamaño quieras que este expandida.

Comment: bien, pero entonces el expand se lo aplico a esta linea? <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show px-3 py-2" id="collapsingNavbar">

Comment: Correcto, en ese `div` que es el que "controla" la nav-bar.

Comment: Probe pero no me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias, busqué la solución para que mi navbar siempre aparezca desplegado y solo aquí se me aclaro las dudas.

```
    <nav class="navbar d-md-block">
    <br>
    <a class="navbar-brand texto_prop" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"alt="" width="70"></a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon active"></span>
   </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a class="nav-link active boton_p" href="principal.php">IR A INICIO 
    <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
    <a class="nav-link active boton_p" href="../public/registraUsuario.php">REGISTRAR USUARIO <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
    <a class="nav-link active boton_p" href="index.php">SALIR<span class="sr-only"></span></a>

     </div>
     </div>
     </nav>
```

Comment: Hola es esto una pregunta? si es así deberías crear una pregunta nueva no usar un a existente. Si esto es una respuesta lo suyo sería añadir una explicación de como funciona y los detalles de la respuesta, no solo código.